# I'm trying to install firebase_storage in flutter but I got error pod can not install error occured

Tags: flutter-dependencies, macos-catalina, podfile

I install this in pubspec.yaml file in flutter and getting error
firebase_storage: ^3.1.5

Comment: What error are you getting? Also ensure it is indented correctly inside the pubspec under dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Is your **Pubspec.yaml** file arranged in a right way. 
It seems your version of Firebase Storage is the latest version.
Your code should look similar to this

[image]

Comment: I installed firebaseStorage and firebaseAuth manually in podfile after that pod install.But still facing error to install build in simulator